How to convert shapefile to geojson using worldwind in Memory not from Disk?
How can I convert shapefile to geojson using WorldWind?
And From Memory InputStream not from disk File like Geotools.
I have created "Shapefile" using WorldWind:
Shapefile shapefile = new Shapefile(shpInputStream, shxInputStream,dbfInputStream, prjInputStream);
  log.debug("shapefile.getShapeType():"+shapefile.getShapeType());

And I can get the shapefile's Bbox and featureNum:
bbox = shapefile.getBoundingRectangle();
            log.debug("bbox[0]:"+bbox[0]);
            log.debug("bbox[1]:"+bbox[1]);
            log.debug("bbox[2]:"+bbox[2]);
            log.debug("bbox[3]:"+bbox[3]);

            int featureNum = shapefile.getNumberOfRecords();
            log.debug("featureNum:"+featureNum);

But how can I convert it into geojson next step?
while (shapefile.hasNext())
{
    ShapefileRecord record = shapefile.nextRecord();

    log.debug("record.getShapeType():"+record.getShapeType());
    log.debug("record.getAttributes():"+record.getAttributes());
    log.debug("record.getAttributes().getValue(\"FCNAME\"):"+record.getAttributes().getValue("FCNAME"));
    log.debug("record.getAttributes().getValue(\"FENAME\"):"+record.getAttributes().getValue("FENAME"));
    log.debug("record.getAttributes().getValue(\"OBJECTID\"):"+record.getAttributes().getValue("OBJECTID"));
    log.debug("record.getAttributes().getValue(\"the_geom\"):"+record.getAttributes().getValue("the_geom"));
    //VecBuffer vb = record.getPointBuffer(0);

    //log.debug("vb.getLocations():"+vb.getLocations());
    //Polygon pgonAirspace = new Polygon(vb.getLocations());
    //log.debug("pgonAirspace.getLocations():"+pgonAirspace.getLocations());
    //break;
}


This is easy to do in GeoTools if that is what want, but this code isn't GeoTools

This answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311330/79) should get you started
